# Connecting to Magento API with SOAP

Tags: magento, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to follow a tutorail on connecting to magento API with Soap, but am stuck already ? SOAP seems to be installed on my sever as i can browse to the ?wsld and it displays an xml file.

I've setup the user and role in magento admin webservices.

i'm confused by 2 things in the tutorial

1. choosing a soap client, In this tutorial we will assume the usage of the PHP SoapClient. **what is this where do i find it** ?
2. Logging with the SOAP client

"So let's create a simple PHP-script that allows us to login into Magento through SOAP. The logic is here that we first need to initialize a new SoapClient object with as argument the Magento SOAP URL."

```
 // Magento login information 
 $mage_url = 'http://MAGENTO/api/?wsdl'; 
$mage_user = 'soap_user'; 
$mage_api_key = '********'; 
// Initialize the SOAP client 
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 
// Login to Magento 
$session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );
```

**Where do you create this script - is it a simple php file ? and how do you actualy make the call - do you just browse to it ?**

http://blog.opensourcenetwork.eu/tutorials/guru/connecting-through-soap-with-magento-1

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You put this into a new blank file. Save this as name.php und run this is on your server:

```
<?php
        $host = "127.0.0.1/magento/index.php"; //our online shop url
        $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle
        $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
        $apikey = "key"; //webservice user pass
        $action = "sales_order.list"; //an action to call later (loading Sales Order List)
        try { 

          $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); //we do login


        print_r($client->call($sess_id, $action));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
            echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage(); //we print this
               exit();
        }
?>
```

Regards boti

Comment: sorry for delay in relplying , so do i just open this file in my browser ? running wamp server 2.1 with Php_soap ext enabled do i need anything esle to run the script ? Many thanks

Comment: yes only run this script in your browser. ;) You need to add an Webservice User and Role in Magento Back-End. Then the Script should work :)

Comment: You can also run these PHP SOAP scripts from the command line eg. php name.php. This is useful when testing as you don't have to report everything back in HTML.

Comment: If i run with above code i am getting error : ==> Error: Error cannot find parameter  mycode : https://justpaste.it/2pdue thanks....

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the `Soap Client` the documents refer to is the built in PHP `SoapClient` object.   There are a plethora of soap client's written in a plethora of different languages.  SOAP, as a protocol, is language/platform independent. (although individual languages/platforms tend to have their own quirks).  Magento provides a Soap **Server**, which can interacted with via a client.  This is client/server architecture.
2. You call this script however you want.  You can load it in an individual web page, you can run it from the command line `$ php script.php`, you can put it in an include files, you can place it in another framework's class files, etc.

Comment: thanks, so do I need to do anything with this soap client, do i have to load I'm not sure how it fits in ? I've written a script.php - i've included the exact code in the question. All i get back if i laod it in the browser is the code minus the first line thanks again PS i use your layoutviewer all the time!

Comment: can't edit question ! here is the code i'm using in the script file <?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/perform-play/api/soap/?wsdl');   
$sessionId = $proxy->login('soap-user', 'greeneyed');
$customerinfo = $proxy->customerInfo($sessionId, 1);  
print_r($customerinfo);

Comment: @Ledgemonkey it sounds like your webserver isn't setup to run PHP scripts.  You may want to find a quick PHP primer before jumping in to using something like the SOAP Api.

Comment: thanks again, sorry for the delay in replying (GMT), I need a bit of quick advice, I have a client who wants to be sent a http post when a customer registers with his store, can this be done fairly easily ? is there a better way to do it like through the soap magento api ? as discussed in this thread - many thanks

Answer (score 3):

this helped alot thanks

> answered Nov 16 '11 at 7:26 boti

You put this into a new blank file. Save this as name.php und run this is on your server:

```
<?php
        $host = "127.0.0.1/magento/index.php"; //our online shop url
        $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle
        $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
        $apikey = "key"; //webservice user pass
        $action = "sales_order.list"; //an action to call later (loading Sales Order List)
        try { 
      $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); //we do login


    print_r($client->call($sess_id, $action));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
        echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage(); //we print this
           exit();
    }
?>
```

HI All,

The solution is :

from Magento Admin Panel...

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls = NO
```

AND !!!!

```
Auto-redirect to Base URL = NO
```

Then Add user from

```
System -> Web Services-> Users
```

Make a user to use with the soapclient

Then make a role from

```
System -> Web Services -> Roles
```

Attach all resources if you want do it this way.

This is important ! add this role to the user you’ve just created

Also Make sure that PHP.ini from

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

Then you can connect with this user I use this code

```
$proxy = new SoapClient(’http://localhost/api/soap/?wsdl’,array( 
$apiuser = "user", 
$apikey = "key"));
```

download soapui from forgesource
http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/?source=directory

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">username</username>
         <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">password</apiKey>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Get the link of our server with link below and save as magentoV2.wsdl

```
http://localhost/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl
```

I hope this will help others because I a lost half a day to understand this simple things because there were no enough detail information on one place.

HR

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the standard SOAP client functionality of PHP(provided, i can't read the link you posted, but I'm assuming it is). Have a look here for more: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: many thanks, Do I need to install this , How does it fit in with connecting to magento API ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i will tel you simple steps, follow those steps then you wii get result as we require.
1. Login to Magento admin panel then navigate to `system-->webservices-->SOAP RPC Roles create SOAP RPC roles`
 2. Navigate to `system-->webservices-->SOAP RPC users` create SOAP RPC user map this user with roles.
 3. Create one PHP file name it as `magentoapi.php` inside `xampp-->htdocs-->folder(project name)`.
 4. Here I am giving you one example, how to get customer Info.
 5. Open  `magentoapi.php` file create one function name it as `customerInfo`

Below is the code:

```
    function customerInfo($api_url, $api_user, $api_pwd) {

        $websites = '' . $api_url . "/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl";
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient($websites);
            $session = $client->login($api_user, $api_pwd);

            $result = $client->call($session, 'customer.info', '1');
            print_r($result);
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Here,
    `$api_url` is your store url,`$api_user`= api user name, `$api_pwd` = api password
    pass this value to the `customerInfo` function. We will get complete information about a particular customer

Do same thing for all functions 
Here is the API reference URL http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html

Finally run the below URL in browser you will get results

http://localhost/yourprojectname/magentoapi.php?functionName=customerLogout&store_url=http://127.0.0.1/magento19&api_username=magento&api_key=123456