# how to call function from zend framework2 to magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, soap

I'm trying to make soap client to connect to a magento server .. and I'm new to this .. and I am learning from [this link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html) 
now I can get a session Id in this code:

```
   <?php
namespace Album\Controller;
use Zend\Soap\Client;
 class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
 {
     public function indexAction()
     {
         $client = new Client("http://localhost/loyal/api/?wsdl");
         $sessionId = $client->login('xxxxxx', '********');


return($client->call($sessionId,'imsales.test'));
     }}
?>
```

but when I call imsales.test it says function $sessionId is not a valid method for this service
and I had same response after this call:

```
return($client->call('imsales.test'));
```

I don't know how to call these functions

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rramii,First of all ,first create an soap user from

Then Add user from

```
System -> Web Services-> Users
```

Make a user to use with the soapclient

Then make a role from

```
System -> Web Services -> Roles
```

Attach all resources if you want do it this way.
then try coding from  the links

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139128/connecting-to-magento-api-with-soap or 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html
```

Comment: thank you for helping :) .. solved in different way: instead of calling $client->call($sessionId,'imsales.test'); .. the new call is $client->getSoapClient()->call($sessionId,'imsales.test'); and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

just if any one came to this page, it solved this way: instead of calling

```
$client->call($sessionId,'imsales.test');
```

the new call is

```
$client->getSoapClient()->call($sessionId,'imsales.test');
```

and it worked for me :)